# User changes lost after adding item to the list

Tags: angularjs

I've got the following code (from this tutorial: http://yeoman.io/codelab/write-app.html):

html:

```
  < form ng-submit="addTodo()" >

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="todo" placeholder="Description" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
      </span>
    </div>

  <div ui-sortable ng-model="todos">
    <p class="input-group" ng-repeat="todo in todos" >
        <input type="text" ng-model="todo" class="form-control" >
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeTodo($index)" aria-label="Remove" >X</button>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="anotherField" class="form-control" >

< /form>
```

js controller:

```
$scope.todos = ['1','2'];

$scope.addTodo = function(){
  $scope.todos.push($scope.todo);
  $scope.todo = '';
};

$scope.removeTodo = function(index){
  $scope.todos.splice(index,1);
};
```

Now the scenario:
1. I add some todos to the list
2. I modify the value of an existing todo item
3. I modify the value of anotherField
4. I add another todo (or remove one of the existing)

After step 4 (which calls addTodo or removeTodo function) modification from step 2 is lost. However, modification from step 3 is still visible.

Why does it behave this way? What should I do to keep the changes after add/remove item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When modifying a todo, you're assigning a new String to the ng-repeat's $scope.todo variable. But that doesn't change the string referenced by your array of todos.

Stop using strings as your model, and use objects with properties instead, and everything will work fine, because the todos array and the ng-repeat will both have a reference to the same object, and will simply modify the property of this same object:

```
<form ng-submit="addTodo()" >

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="todo.description" placeholder="Description" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
      </span>
    </div>

  <div ui-sortable ng-model="todos">
    <p class="input-group" ng-repeat="todo in todos" >
        <input type="text" ng-model="todo.description" class="form-control" >
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeTodo($index)" aria-label="Remove" >X</button>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>

</form>
```

and

```
$scope.todos = [
    {
        description: '1'
    }, 
    { 
        description: '2'
    }
];

$scope.todo = {
    description: ''
}

$scope.addTodo = function() {
  $scope.todos.push($scope.todo);
  $scope.todo = {
      description: ''
  };
};

$scope.removeTodo = function(index){
  $scope.todos.splice(index,1);
};
```